# CakePHP: $user[$this->Auth->getModel()->alias]?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having difficulty understanding what's going on here

```
class AppController extends Controller {
...
public function beforeFilter() {
    $user = $this->Auth->user();
    if (!empty($user)) {            
        Configure::write('User', $user[$this->Auth->getModel()->alias]);
    }
}
...
}
```

In my example...

1. $user = Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => user [active] => 1 [email] => user@site.com )
2. $this->Auth->getModel()->alias = 'User' (string)
3. $user[$this->Auth->getModel()->alias] = Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => user [active] => 1 [email] => user@site.com )

My questions:

1. How are $user['User'] and $user the same thing? It looks to me $user is an associative array with keys id, username, active, and email. I'm not sure how using the key 'User' works.
2. Could someone explain the "::" syntax and what Configure::write('User', ...) does and how to access this 'User' variable (probably has some conventional term for it..). I'm finding that Configure::read('User') retrieve this information. Is this right?
3. Finally.. I'm confused between two terms User (model as in $this->User->create() to create a new user) and User (from Configure::write('User',...)). They are not the same things, are they?

Comment: `::` is for calling static methods of a class. Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different models together with the AuthComponent. The default is `User`, but you may make it `Member`, `Admin` or whatever else your user models are called. Calling `$this->Auth->user()` returns an array with that primary name attached to it, like:

```
array(
    'Admin' => array(
        'id' => ...
        ...
    )
)
```

(I suspect you're debugging your `$user` variable wrong there.)

The only thing that block of code does is to write the user details into the Configuration (just a place to store values) without this intermediate `Admin` key. I guess this is so any piece of code anywhere can get at the current user details without having to worry about whether it's `$user['User']` or `$user['Admin']` or something else. Instead you can simply use `Configure::read('User')` or `Configure::read('User.id')` or `Configure::read('User.name')` etc.

The choice of the name `User` in `Configure::write('User', ...)` is entirely arbitrary. You could use anything there, it has no predefined meaning.

BTW, if it's just the controller, you can get the details of the current user without worrying about what the user model is called using `$this->Auth->user('name')` (to get the name, for example).

Comment: so, how does $user['User'] work as $user doesn't have "User" as one of its keys? Is it CakePHP-specific? Also, what is the "->alias" part? I couldn't find it in the AuthComponent documentation.

Comment: @user `$user` as returned by `$this->Auth->user()` *does have* a key `'User'`. As I said, I think you're just looking in the wrong place. `Auth->getModel()->alias` gets the alias (the name) of the model which is used for authentication. So if `Admin` is currently used for authentication, it'll give you `'Admin'`, if `User`, `'User'` etc.

Answer (score 0):

$user['User'] and $user can't be the same thing. What code did you use to check the content of $user['User'] and $user?
"::" is how you access class functions and variables. "->" is how you access object functions and variables. It does not allow access to 'User' variable (it's just string, not a variable). So `Configure::write()` you are calling the write() class method in class Configure.

$this->User->create() and Configure::write('User',...) are completely different things. $this->User is an object of the User class. 'User' is just a string.

Finally, what that piece of code does is copy the logged in User record in the session (stored by the Auth component) to the runtime configuration singleton class Configure. That `$this->Auth->getModel()->alias` is just to get the key of $user array. Because Auth can be configured to use another model to authenticate.

Comment: `print_r($user['User']);` and `print_r($user);` right after `$user = $this->Auth->user();`. I'm looking at the outputs right now, and they are the same, and they are both "Array".